# I want to abstract By class in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I want to abstract By class in selenium so that I can write code in page classes that is independent of Selenium. I'd tried the following:

```
interface Element{

By id(String id);

By name(String name);

By className(String className);

By tagName(String tagName);

By xpath(String xpath);

By cssSelector(String cssSelector);

By linkText(String linkText);

By partialLinkText(String partialLinkText);

}


class Locator {

public static By id(String id) {
    return By.id(id);

}

public static By name(String name) {
    return By.name(name);
}

public  By className(String className) {
    return By.className(className);
}

public By tagName(String tagName) {
return By.tagName(tagName);
}

public By xpath(String xpathExpression) {
    return By.xpath(xpathExpression);
}

public By cssSelector(String cssSelector) {
    return By.cssSelector(cssSelector);
}

public By linkText(String linkText) {
    return By.linkText(linkText);
}

public By partialLinkText(String partialLinkText) {
    return By.partialLinkText(partialLinkText);
}


}
```

In this way I had to create Locator class object. I don't want to create Locator class object. I want the methods to be static so that I can just call the methods with class name. But we can't have static methods as they have to be defined in the interface itself.

How can By class can be abstracted so that it can be a page class can be implemented such that every element will become a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a class which accepts the locator type and locator value as parameters in constructor. Now pass the value to the identifier class to form the locators. And create a class with all locator type as methods to accept the string value. You can have all locator type as Enum for readability.

pseudo code example:-

```
Enum locatorType{
 id,
 class,
 ...
}

class identifier{
identifier(locatorType lt,String value){
 switch(lt.name()){
 //call the By.ltname(value) passing the value;
...
}
class BY extends By{
 public By id(value){
  //form the findElement;
 }
 ...//similarly for all the locators
}
```

Once the identifier is created. we can use the object to be passed to a method wrapper to implement all the webDriver methods(click,sendKeys, etc) using the object created.

hope this solves your problem.